# Haskell, type matching problems

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch

I cannot understand why the function:

```
repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli xs n = concatMap (replicate n) xs
```

cannot be rewritten as:

```
repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli [] _ = []
repli (x:xs) n = (take n $ repeat x) : repli xs n
```

or

```
repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli [] _ = []
repli (x:xs) n = (replicate n x) : repli xs n
```

Ghci complains:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a]’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
      at 99questions.hs:41:10
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a] (bound at 99questions.hs:43:10)
  x :: a (bound at 99questions.hs:43:8)
  repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a] (bound at 99questions.hs:42:1)
In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(replicate n x)’
In the expression: (replicate n x) : repli xs n
```

I don't understand why, since doing all the type computations it turns out ok. `repeat x` is `[a]` and so `take n` is `[a]`. Therefore it shouldn't complain.

Comment: I'm not clear on your intent - why do you pass a list as the argument? It seems like you are trying to recreate `replicate` which works on single elements.

Comment: @shree.pat18: Yes, that's the exercise. I am going through Haskell's 99 problems list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `(:)` is `a -> [a] -> [a]`. Therefore, you cannot have lists on both sides of the operator. That's the cause of your error.

You could instead use `(++)`, which has the signature `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: And in the first function (the working one) there was even **concat** Map!